# How to import multiple components from a directory in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, es6-modules

I have a directory with multiple react components. How can I import all components in a single line (from directory) **without exporting components in separate index.js**

```
src/
   components/
      comp1.js
      comp2.js
      comp3.js
      comp4.js
```

Requirement:

```
import {comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4} from 'src/components';
```

Are there any webpack/babel plugins to achieve this? Or something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [babel-plugin-import-directory](https://github.com/Anmo/babel-plugin-import-directory#readme) plugin elimminates the use index.js

It can be used in webpack,

```
module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: ['babel-plugin-import-directory']
                }
            }
        },
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `index.js` file in components folder.

```
src/
   components/
      comp1.js
      comp2.js
      comp3.js
      comp4.js
      index.js
```

**index.js**

If comp1.js contains a named export like  `export {Comp1}` or `export const Comp1 = ()=>{}` export the files in index as follows

```
export * from './comp1.js'
export * from './comp2.js'
```

if comp1.js contains default export like `export default Comp1` export the files in index as follows

```
export {default as Comp1} from './comp1.js'
export {default as Comp2} from './comp2.js'
```

Now You can import it as `import {comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4} from '../components';`

In order to import as `"src/components"` , you need to add [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) to your webpack config

Comment: I need a solution without index.js! Thanks!